# Showing that $\mathbb{C}$\ {$x+iy|x,y\in \mathbb{Q}$} is connected

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

This I find it really hard to solve. I suppose the set  {$x+iy|x,y\in \mathbb{Q}$} is neither closed or open. But I just cannot seem to find a way to go forward. Can someone help me out. Thanks

Comment: Consider paths consisting of straight lines parallel to the axes?

Comment: @MarkBennet Nice idea but suppose I chose z with rational Rez and irrational Imz and $z_0$ with irrational $Rez_0$ and rational $Imz_0$ Do you think we can construct straight lines which will not have z with both rational components?

Comment: You should be able to join points using at most three lines. The example you give takes just two. Go along $Imz$ until you get to $Rez_0$ and then go up or down. Then you have fixed one component as irrational on both lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kind of dual to [a question asked just yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1013994/1508). The solution is similar: every point in your set is path-connected to the point $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2i$, so every point is path-connected to every other point.

Indeed, if $a \notin \mathbb Q$, then we have a path $a+bi \to a+\sqrt 2i \to \sqrt 2+\sqrt 2i$; the case $b \notin \mathbb Q$ is similar.

(I suppose I shouldn't say that two points are "path-connected", because that adjective properly applies to the whole set; but you know what I mean.)

Comment: Just the answer I was waiting for. This is brilliant and simple thanks

Comment: You can say "two points are connected by a path".

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** Find a path connecting 2 points with both coordinates irrational.

**Hint 2:** Connect all points with one coordinate irrational to a point with both coordinates irrational.

Comment: Are you saying that  C \ {x+iy|x,y∈Q} contains complex numbers with real and imaginary parts which are only irrational?

Comment: @Heisenberg I don't understand your question.

Comment: It seems to me from your answer that $z\in$ C \ {x+iy|x,y∈Q} means Rez AND Imz are both irrational

Comment: @Heisenberg No, see hint 2.

Comment: Ah sorry for overlooking that. I will try to solve this